# Embed Facebook Group Plugin in Website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Much like [Facebook's Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), is there a way to embed a Facebook group "badge" onto a website?

Comment: No, there isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they have a Group Plugin. Follow their instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/group-plugin

Unfortunately, it's fixed-width only.